# _.each, unable to assign gamepieces to a gameboard

Tags: underscore.js

I am trying to iterate through a gameboard, which is an array of arrays, and assign game pieces to each square. I was able to do this with a nested for loop but not using _.each. I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '#<Object>' of undefined
```

My code is below:

```
_.each(gameBoard, function(row, index, list) {
  _.each(row, function(square) {
    makePiece(gameBoard, [row, square], 'bomberman');
    gameBoard[row][square].gamePiece.imageURL =    
      "http://vectorlib.free.fr/BomberMan/jpg/bomberman.jpg"; 
  });
});
```

Comment: at what line do you get the error? needs more information...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much information, so this answer my not be spot on, but I did notice that you access your `gameBoard` like so: `gameBoard[row][square]`. if your game board is a matrix, you would want to access positions in that matrix by using the indices underscore is providing you, and not by the items you are currently iterating on!!

try something like this:

```
_.each(gameBoard, function(row, j, matrix) {
  _.each(row, function(square, i, array) {
    makePiece(gameBoard, [row, square], 'bomberman');
    gameBoard[j][i].gamePiece.imageURL =    
      "http://vectorlib.free.fr/BomberMan/jpg/bomberman.jpg"; 
  });
});
```